# Backend Health Unhealthy in Azure. Connectivity Test failed

Tags: azure

I have created a application gateway in Azure. I have redirected all the traffic from application gateway onto a domain name using private DNS. The application gateway got created successfully. But, I am not able to access the private domain. The backend health says unhealthy.The Backend health says:

> Time taken by the backend to respond to application gateway's health probe is more than the timeout threshold in the probe setting.30 sec is the standard timeout.

I have increased the timeout to 30 and 40 as well but it still says unhealthy. Also when I do a connectivity test, It says NSG rules success but Connectivity test failed.
Probes sent 30, Failed 30.
I have tried everything from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-backend-health-troubleshooting
as well. But it still says unhealthy.
Any leads on how to solve this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please share your terraform code.

Comment: I tried to deploy manually on azure.